# Mean of MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following dataframe

```
                 A     B    C    D    E    F
Algo     T                                   
X        1     0.2   0.2  0.0  0.0  0.2   0.2
         2     0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
Y        15    0.7   1.4  1.5  1.0  0.7   1.4
         30    0.5   0.3  1.0  0.4  0.5   0.4
         45    0.2   0.0  0.6  0.0  0.2   0.0
Z        30    1.8   2.3  0.6  0.7  1.8   2.3
         60    1.0   0.5  0.3  0.4  1.0   0.5
         90    0.3   0.2  0.0  0.2  0.4   0.2
```

And I would like know how to have a row at the bottom showing the mean values for columns A, B, C, ... F

```
                 A     B    C    D    E    F
Algo     T                                   
X        1     0.2   0.2  0.0  0.0  0.2   0.2
         2     0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
Y        15    0.7   1.4  1.5  1.0  0.7   1.4
         30    0.5   0.3  1.0  0.4  0.5   0.4
         45    0.2   0.0  0.6  0.0  0.2   0.0
Z        30    1.8   2.3  0.6  0.7  1.8   2.3
         60    1.0   0.5  0.3  0.4  1.0   0.5
         90    0.3   0.2  0.0  0.2  0.4   0.2
Mean           ...   ...  ...  ...  ...   ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the mean row using `.loc`. Values of a `MultiIndex` are tuples, so assign accordingly:

```
df.loc[('Mean', ''), :] = df.mean()
```

#### Output:

```
              A       B    C       D    E      F
Algo T                                          
X    1   0.2000  0.2000  0.0  0.0000  0.2  0.200
     2   0.0000  0.0000  0.0  0.0000  0.0  0.000
Y    15  0.7000  1.4000  1.5  1.0000  0.7  1.400
     30  0.5000  0.3000  1.0  0.4000  0.5  0.400
     45  0.2000  0.0000  0.6  0.0000  0.2  0.000
Z    30  1.8000  2.3000  0.6  0.7000  1.8  2.300
     60  1.0000  0.5000  0.3  0.4000  1.0  0.500
     90  0.3000  0.2000  0.0  0.2000  0.4  0.200
Mean     0.5875  0.6125  0.5  0.3375  0.6  0.625
```

---

If you want a separate mean for each group, then concatenate. Here we can use `.agg` specifying a list and `stack` to get the `MultiIndex` we need without much manual manipulation. You can now generalize to multiple aggregation functions `.agg(['mean', 'std', 'size'])` and it will add all of those with the agg function in the `T` index level.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df, df.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean']).stack(1)])

                  A         B         C         D         E    F
Algo T                                                          
X    1     0.200000  0.200000  0.000000  0.000000  0.200000  0.2
     2     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
Y    15    0.700000  1.400000  1.500000  1.000000  0.700000  1.4
     30    0.500000  0.300000  1.000000  0.400000  0.500000  0.4
     45    0.200000  0.000000  0.600000  0.000000  0.200000  0.0
Z    30    1.800000  2.300000  0.600000  0.700000  1.800000  2.3
     60    1.000000  0.500000  0.300000  0.400000  1.000000  0.5
     90    0.300000  0.200000  0.000000  0.200000  0.400000  0.2
X    mean  0.100000  0.100000  0.000000  0.000000  0.100000  0.1
Y    mean  0.466667  0.566667  1.033333  0.466667  0.466667  0.6
Z    mean  1.033333  1.000000  0.300000  0.433333  1.066667  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I adapt this to three separate means, one for each type of Algo?

Comment: @J.Kuhn see my edit. I think it makes the most sense to have `mean` go in the `1st` level of the `MultiIndex` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you actually want to have a row in the same df for mean, then you can:

1. Get a pd.Series of the mean values.
2. Give it a name that will conform to a MultiIndex.
3. Append it to the DataFrame.

   ```
   df = df.append(df.mean().rename(('Mean', '')))
   ```